# How to give permissions write and Read to a mount folder in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I want to do a binding (mount volume) between the jupyterLab and the VM. The only problem is the permissions, the folder that I create `(/home/jovyan/work)` always have a root permissions. I cannot create anything inside. I tried many solutions: In a docker file I tried this solution:

```
FROM my_image
RUN if [[ -d "$HOME/toto" ]] ; then echo OK ; else mkdir "$HOME/toto" ; fi
RUN chmod 777 $HOME/toto
```

==> always I got no permissions on the mounted folder

```
ARG NB_DIR=/tmp/lab_share
RUN mkdir "$NB_DIR"
RUN chown :100 "$NB_DIR"
RUN chmod g+rws "$NB_DIR"
RUN apt-get install acl
RUN setfacl -d -m g::rwx "$NB_DIR"
USER root
```

==> The problem here is the setfacl is not recognized in the container, I tried to install it just before, always not acceptable.

I tried to add a GRANT_SUDO in the jupyterHub service

```
extraEnv:
      GRANT_SUDO: "yes"
```

==> The problem here is the extraEnv is not recognized

I tried to create a method in the jupyterHub_config file, just after the binding code:

```
    notebook_dir = os.environ.get('DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR') or '/home/jovyan/work'
    c.DockerSpawner.notebook_dir = notebook_dir
    c.DockerSpawner.volumes = { "/tmp/{username}" :notebook_dir}
    c.DockerSpawner.remove_containers = True


##### CREATE HOOKER
def create_dir_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name # get the username
    logger.info(f"### USERNAME {username}")
    volume_path = os.path.join('/tmp', username)
    logger.info(f"### USERNAME {volume_path}")
    if not os.path.exists(volume_path):
        # create a directory with umask 0755
        # hub and container user must have the same UID to be writeable
        # still readable by other users on the system
        logger.info(f"FOLDER FOR USER {username} not existing")
        logger.info(f"CREATING A FOLDER IN {volume_path}")
        os.mkdir(volume_path, 0o777)
        # now do whatever you think your user needs
        # ...
    logger.info("coucou")
# attach the hook function to the spawner
c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = create_dir_hook
```

In this solutions the compilator don't read all the if bloc, even the else bloc. I found in the docker doc, that is a famous issue in docker, but I didn't find it's solution. Really I need your help please, if you have any solution I will be appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you bind-mount a directory into a container `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path`, all of the contents, permissions, and properties of the host path replace what's in the image.  Nothing you do in a Dockerfile will have any effect because the bind mount will replace it.  You probably also need to `docker run -u $(id -u)` so the container runs as the current host user, which presumably has permissions to use the current directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for answer.
Should I add docker run -u $(id -u) in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: No, in the Dockerfile you can't know the host user ID on the system where the image will eventually run.  It needs to be an option when you start the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze this is a useful suggestion.  When I use this, I also get a non fatal error "/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID xxxxxxxx".  It's ok, just a minor annoyance.